# How to extract part of a string in HIVE?

Tags: sql, string, hive, hiveql

I am looking to do this in Hive. The following is a query that works in sql server.

```
select LEFT('ENTERPRISE > DEMO', CHARINDEX('>', 'ENTERPRISE > DEMO') - 2)
```

Basically I want to extract all characters in my string to the left of `>`. Also, the number of characters that can appear before this `>` sign is variable. 
There is no `LEFT` function in hive. How can I use `substr` or `regexp_extract` for this?

Answer (score 2):

Also in addition to already provided solutions with `regexp_extract` and `substr()`+`instr()`, you can use `split()`:

```
hive> select split('ENTERPRISE > DEMO','>')[0];
OK
ENTERPRISE
Time taken: 0.099 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select split('ENTERPRISE > DEMO','>')[1];
OK
 DEMO
Time taken: 0.072 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Apply trim() if you want to remove spaces:

```
hive> select trim(split('ENTERPRISE > DEMO','>')[0]);
OK
ENTERPRISE
```

Or you can split by any number of spaces+'>'+any number of spaces. split() uses regexp, no necessary to use trim():

```
hive> select trim(split('ENTERPRISE >DEMO',' *?> *?')[0]);
OK
ENTERPRISE
Time taken: 0.075 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!!! The trim/split worked better and helped removes some issues that I was getting with spaces.

Comment: @buddykumar If you are satisfied with my answer please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

HIVE supports INSTR which returns basically the same function as CHARINDEX but the input field and test value are the opposite way round in the function, so I'd try

```
SELECT SUBSTR('ENTERPRISE > DEMO',1,INSTR('ENTERPRISE > DEMO','>') -2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1) a combination of `substring` and `instr`

```
trim(substring(val,1,instr(val,'>')-1))
```

2) `regexp_extract`

```
trim(regexp_extract(val,'(^.*)>',1))
```